# Negative selection cannot be deleted from solr index

Tags: solr

I have documents in solr index that do not have date field. I want to remove all such documents. Following does not work, even though

date:[* TO *]

produces documents I want to keep, and

-date:[* TO *]

produces documents I want to delete.
`/usr/bin/curl http:// localhost:8080/solr/update -H "Content-Type: text/xml" --data-binary '<delete><query>-date:[* TO *]</query></delete>'
/usr/bin/curl http:// localhost:8080/solr/update -H "Content-Type: text/xml" --data-binary '<commit/>'
/usr/bin/curl http:// localhost:8080/solr/update -H "Content-Type: text/xml" --data-binary '<optimize/>'`

Result:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
<int name="status">0</int>
<int name="QTime">16</int>
</lst></response>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><response><lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">0</int><int name="QTime">140</int></lst></response>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><response>
<lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">0</int><int name="QTime">41</int></lst>
</response>`

Note: Deleting date:[* TO *] documents works well.

Comment: Solution is to delete `*:* -date:[* TO *]`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The solution was to add an additional condition which refers to the id. So that I had in the end

```
<delete><query>-date:[* TO *] AND id:(*)</query></delete>
```

As you can see the id can have any value.

Answer (score 1):

```
/update?stream.body=<delete><query>*:* -(date:[* TO *])</query></delete>&commit=true
```

Edit: some one down-voted my answer because I didn't explain it. Here it is:

1. `*:*` means all documents
2. `date:[* TO *]` means all documents which have a date field
3. `*:* -(date:[* TO *])` all documents which don't have a date field
4. `commit=true` means commit the change to index

Why `<delete><query>-date:[* TO *]</query></delete>` doesn't work? Frankly speaking, I am not sure. The syntax for updating is not the same as the syntax for querying. I will post more if I figure out more in the future.